# JavaScript code breaks after "for" loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I wrote a simple geolocation code, that, for some reason, breaks... Please refer to comments in the part of code quoted below, which show where everything is fine and from which point it breaks.

```
var city = "Unknown";
var area = "Unknown";
var lr = w.results.length;
for (var n = 0; n <= lr; n++)
{
    var la = w.results[n].address_components.length;
    for (var m = 0; m <= la; m++)
    {
        if (w.results[n].address_components[m].types[0] == "locality")
        {
            city = w.results[n].address_components[m].long_name;
            break;
        }
        else if (w.results[n].address_components[m].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_2")
        {
            area = w.results[n].address_components[m].long_name;
            break;
        }
    } //Whatever I put here, still works
} //Now it breaks, and everything below never runs
if (city == "Unknown")
{
    city = area;
}
```

I'm running it in Tasker (Android) and got no errors that could give a hint. Must be a dumb mistake, though. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Or at least provide us what is the value of w.results.

Comment: <= should be changed to <

Comment: You should check if variable la is not undefined or 0.

Comment: Ruben Karapetyan, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never leave the for loop, that's why it doesn't work.

You could use below an `if(condition) { break; }` below the second `for` loop.
Just find what to use as condition.

Comment: Which for loop are you saying is never being left? Why would that be?

Comment: The first for loop is never being left, so it keeps running over and over again, that's why the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels to break out of nested for loops. 
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label )

Another way is to set the m variable to lr+1, before breaking, but that will still run the remainder of the outer loop once before continuing.

```
var city = "Unknown";
var area = "Unknown";
var lr = w.results.length;
outer:
for (var n = 0; n <= lr; n++)
{
    var la = w.results[n].address_components.length;
inner:
    for (var m = 0; m <= la; m++)
    {
        if (w.results[n].address_components[m].types[0] == "locality")
        {
            city = w.results[n].address_components[m].long_name;
            break outer;
        }
        else if (w.results[n].address_components[m].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_2")
        {
            area = w.results[n].address_components[m].long_name;
            break outer;
        }
    } //Whatever I put here, still works
} //Now it breaks, and everything below never runs
if (city == "Unknown")
{
    city = area;
}
```